# How do I pass parameters with eval in src property.

Tags: asp.net

How do I do this syntactically?

```
   src='<%# "HttpImageHandler.jpg?imagename=" +  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"imagename").ToString() %>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> src='<%# Eval("imagename","HttpImageHandler.jpg?imagename={0}") %>'

Answer (score 2):

`src='HttpImageHandler.jpg?imagename=<%# Eval("imagename") %>'`